# Problem with including dll files to project

Tags: codeblocks

I need help with an error:

```
C:\SQLAPI\bin\libsqlapid.dll: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I successfully added these files:

```
C:\SQLAPI\lib\libsqlapiddll.a
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libuser32.a
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libversion.a
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\liboleaut32.a
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libole32.a
```

in Settings->Compiler->Global Compiler Settings->Linker Settings

But I'm still getting the error.

Build log:

Comment: The reported error reads like you are not building an executable, so linking is not being performed. If you are compiling a library, cool. If not, check your other compiler options because something's gotten messed up. Adding the generated compiler command line to the question may provide further hints someone familiar with Code::Blocks can use to help you out.

Comment: I thought that C:\SQLAPI\lib\libsqlapiddll.a will work, but I was wrong ;(

Comment: Should I add something in other settings? I'm reading this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-connectivity-using-cc/

Comment: Post the _complete_ build log - the plain-text one one.  It contains the diagnostic information required to help you.  Although why is the .dll file even being used as an input file?  You've added the export libs, but you need to _remove_ the dll.  That is linked at runtime - the clue is in the name!

Comment: It says `Build log:` at the end of your question, but there are no logs presented there. Did you intend to add something?